# Handling the result of a SQLite aggregate function on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I'm working on an app (SleepTracker) and I'm trying to put together a statistic feature based on data saved in a SQLite database using different aggregate functions. What I'm trying to achieve is to query the table with an aggregate function that I've wrote already, and store the result in a string that is bound to a textblock on the View.

However, I can't figure out how I would go about doing this because it only seems to work if the results are stored in some sort of list like an OC which seems to be overkill for just needing a single result such as a count, or a max value. Is there a way that I could achieve this that I'm completely ignoring?

For example, here's what I'm working with:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.ConnectionString))
{
    var latestTime = @"SELECT time(max(SleepTime))
                       FROM SleepTrackerModel
                       WHERE Date > (SELECT DATETIME('now', '-7 day'))";
    conn.Query<SleepTrackerModel>(latestTime);
}
```

Then I have a string "LatestTime" which is bound to a textblock on the View. I was hoping that the result of the query could just be stored as the value of that string and that'd be it, but it doesn't seem to work like that.

**Edit**
Maybe I could use ExecuteScalar? So maybe I could try something like;

```
LatestTime = conn.CreateCommand(latestTime).ExecuteScalar<string>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem and I'll post the answer in case anyone runs into the problem.

I tried out the ExecuteScalar() code and it's giving me the result I need where the result of the query is stored in a string and bound to the appropriate textblock. Here's some code;

```
var query = @"SELECT time(max(MyTime))
              FROM YourTable";
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(your connection string))
{
    // MaxTime being a string that is bound to the textblock on the view.
    MaxTime = db.CreateCommand(query).ExecuteScalar<string>();
}
```